# disable scrolling of listview doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

Am actually using a nested listview. Parent listview is with custom adapter and normal listview for child.

I know i can use `expandable list view`. But child items are more complicated to handle them in my scenario. Have many components.

Here is what i tried, clicking on a button in parent list shows corresponding child list items. That's working fine. But only problem is scrolling. I wanted to scroll child list, but parent list is scrolling. I tried both `setScrollContainer(false)` and `setClickable(false)` (just tried) for parent, but no use.

This is my code.

activity_main.xml

> 

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="View" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parent_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b_view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/child_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/parent_rel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/parent_rel"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ch_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

> public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
ListView lv;
String[] prnt_items = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
boolean isViewing = false;
RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    lv.setAdapter(new ParentItems());

}

class ParentItems extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return prnt_items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return prnt_items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final View p_v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) p_v.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);

        tv.setText(prnt_items[position]);
        Button sub_view = (Button) p_v.findViewById(R.id.b_view);

        sub_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isViewing) {
                    lv.setScrollContainer(false);
                    //lv.setClickable(false);
                    isViewing = !isViewing;
                    layout = (RelativeLayout) p_v.findViewById(R.id.child_view);
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ListView c_lv = (ListView) p_v.findViewById(R.id.ch_listView);
                    c_lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            new String[] { "Hello", "Hai", "Oops!!!" }));
                    c_lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Click @ " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }

                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(layout !=null){
                        isViewing = !isViewing;
                        lv.setScrollContainer(true);
                        //lv.setClickable(true);
                        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return p_v;
    }
}
```

}

Appreciate for the help.

Thanks.